# sql only return rows that have certain column values

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

With my tables above how can I return the  `user_id`(s) which belong to companies that are only in `type_id` = 34 and 35 and not belonging in `type_id`= 8. So since `comp_id` = 3 isnt in `type_id`= 8 and is in `type_id`= 34 and 35 therefore **results should be `user_id`=104 and 105**

Im looking for users who are in companies both `type_id`=34 and 35 not either or. If it is not in 34 but in 35 then users from that company should not be returned.

Comment: the answer that you accepted will return also user_ids that are only type_id=34 or only type_id=35. In your question you mention twice 34 **and** 35.

Comment: @forpas: you may be right, I think the question is not entirely clear there. Since the OP says 'companies that are only **in** `type_id` =34 and 35, I understood he meant  one of the two, but not necessarily both.

Comment: *and* means both, *or* means any of the two.

Comment: and _in_ may mean either. It would be great if the OP cleared this up. I am not saying you are wrong, I am just saying it was confusing to me.

Comment: Now that you clarified, why did you accept an answer that does not meet your requirement?

Comment: @forpas the 2nd query meets my criteria. Dont want companies that are in 8

Comment: No it does not meet your criteria. It will return  user_ids that have only type_id = 34 or only type_id = 35 because they are both not 8.

Comment: @forpas ah youre right.

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation to get the `comp_id`s that meet your conditions and with the operator `IN` get the `user_id`s:

```
select user_id 
from Table_2
where comp_id in (
  select comp_id
  from Table_1
  group by comp_id
  having sum(type_id not in (34, 35)) = 0
     and sum(type_id in (34, 35)) = 2
)
```

If there are other `type_id`s than 34, 35 and 8 and they are also allowed as long as 34 and 35 exist but not 8 then:

```
select user_id 
from Table_2
where comp_id in (
  select comp_id
  from Table_1
  group by comp_id
  having sum(type_id = 8) = 0
     and sum(type_id in (34, 35)) = 2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple and readable way to do it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id 
FROM Table_2
WHERE comp_id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT comp_id
    FROM Table_1
    WHERE type_id IN (34, 35)
    MINUS
    SELECT DISTINCT comp_id
    FROM Table_1
    WHERE type_id IN (8)
)
```

If your database doesn't support SELECT DISTINCT then just use SELECT and add a GROUP BY comp_id to the bottom of each SELECT statement. Capitalisation of keywords is optional. If you already have a big WHERE statement for Table_2 you can use an inner join to the sub-select instead of an IN.

-- EDIT: to avoid the use of MINUS for MySQL --
Confession: I'm not able to test this SQL in MySQL at the moment

```
SELECT DISTINCT Table_2.user_id 
FROM Table_2
INNER JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT comp_id
      FROM Table_1
      WHERE type_id IN (34, 35)
     ) type_include ON Table_2.type_id = type_include.type_id
LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT comp_id
      FROM Table_1
      WHERE type_id IN (8)
     ) type_exclude ON Table_2.type_id = type_exclude.type_id
                   AND type_exclude.type_id IS NULL
```

Comment: MySql does not support MINUS.

Answer (score 0):

You can do such a thing with a subquery, in which you specify the condition that should not be met

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.user_id 
    FROM Table_2 t2 
JOIN Table_1 t1 
    ON ((t1.comp_id = t2.comp_id) 
      AND ((type_id = 34) OR (type_id = 35))
      AND t1.comp_id NOT IN (SELECT comp_id FROM Table_1 WHERE type_id = 8)
    )
;
```

PS: For the data in your example, you would not even have to check for the ID being equal to 35 or 34 as there are no other values in your data anyway.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.user_id 
    FROM Table_2 t2 
    WHERE t2.comp_id NOT IN (SELECT comp_id FROM Table_1 WHERE type_id = 8)
;
```

**EDIT:** As was correctly pointed out, the first query will

- also include user_ids for which Table_1 only has rows with *either* `type_id = 34` *or* `type_id = 35` and not only with *both*
- also include user_ids for which Table_1 has rows that additionally to 34 or 35 may have *another* `type_id` other than 8 (which is not present in the example, but may happen in other data)

This is by design, as I understood the question requiring this. If this is not the intended result, please look at the answer from @forpas (https://stackoverflow.com/a/63382574/14015737), which yields a result that does neither of the above.

Comment: I am using the 2nd solution. Im looking for 34 "and" 35 not either 34 or 35. Yes there are other type_ids there other than 8, 34 and 35. It's ok if the corp_id are in those types. I just dont want them in type_id 8 at all.